# how can i restrict no of specific rows in print page for a HTML table in using css , javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, css

i am printing a table using javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function printpreview(divId) {
    var content = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');    

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write('<div align="center"><h2> MANAGEMENT</h2></div>');
    mywindow.document.write('<div align="center"><h3>Sales Records</h3></div>');
    mywindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/public/css/style.css\" 
    type=\"text/css\"/>");
    mywindow.document.write(content);
    mywindow.document.write('<p style="color: #5B5745; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold;">' );
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}
```

i am using a footer in my print page using below code

```
mywindow.document.write('<div class="footer-text">Copyright 2019 Resource Planing System. All rights reserved.</div></p> </div>');
```

and the css is

```
.footer-text { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

but my footer page is overlapping with the above table , now to avoid this i want to restrict no of some specific rows printing per page , can any one help me how can i restrict no of rows per page , i have tried the below code , but its only working in IE and not chrome. i need the solution in chrome

```
@media print  {            
    tr:nth-of-type(n){
        page-break-after:always;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could perhaps use `flex-box` to layout the page - that way you could ensure the footer is always at the bottom and that other elements  do not overlap it

Comment: can u please explain it a bit more, any example how to use flex-box? new to css so dont know about it

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really more how to have a footer always at the bottom of the page that other content will not interfere with then you can implement [a `sticky footer`](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) very easily using [`flexboxes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

I put together a quick demo ~ observe that the `footer` element remains at the very bottom of the page and none of the other content affects it or overlaps/obscures it which is, I think, what you were hoping for.

( ignore the contents of the table - it's just a mix of dummy data to "flesh out" the HTML table for display )

The key for this to work is to assign `flex:1` to the `main` element where the header and footer do not have this. Other values for all three are possible to alter the layout yet further - perhaps getting to [play with Flexboxes](https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) might help?!

I added a button that inserts clones of the HTML table so you can see that the footer remains a footer at the bottom despite all other content.

Good luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Basic Flexbox: Sticky Footer</title>
        <style>
            body{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:100vh; box-sizing:border-box; margin:0; padding:0; font-family:monospace }

            main, header, footer{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; width:100%; margin:auto; }

            header{ order:1; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background:rgba(0,0,200,0.1); }
            main{ order:2; flex:2; align-items:flex-start; justify-content:flex-start; background:rgba(0,200,0,0.1) }
            footer{ order:3; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background:rgba(200,0,0,0.1); }

            table{ margin:1rem; border:1px solid gray; border-collapse:collapse; box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,255,0.5) }
            td{ border:1px solid gray }
            table > caption{ margin:auto; background:gray; color:white}

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>A meaningful header</header>

        <main>

            <input type='button' value='Add table' />

            <table>
                <caption>A meaningful table showing meaningful stuff</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td>Measurement(s)</td>
                    <td>DNA methylation profiling data • whole genome sequencing assay • bisulfite sequencing assay • transcription profiling assay</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Technology Type(s)</td>
                    <td>DNA methylation profiling assay • DNA sequencing • RNA sequencing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Factor Type(s)</td>
                    <td>age • sex • smoking status</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sample Characteristic - Organism</td>
                    <td>Homo sapiens</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><p>Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh.</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><p>Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna.</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><p>Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet.</p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </main>

        <footer>Copyright 2019 Resource Planning System. All rights deserved, all wrongs reversed.</footer>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                e.target.parentNode.appendChild( e.target.parentNode.querySelector('table').cloneNode( true ) )
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```